# Alterar valores sequencias de um array multidimensional

Tags: php, array-multidimensional

No Framework que desenvolvo (linguagem PHP), eu utilizo array multidimensional para geração de relatórios HTML.

Existe um relatório em particular que não consigo ordenar devidamente na consulta SQL, tendo somente todos os dados pelos quais desejo ordenamento após formação do array.

Exemplo do array:

```
$dados[] = array(

    $cont++,"<nobr>".$nome."</nobr>",
    "<div align=\"center\">".$this->tipoCliente($r['taxa'])."</div>",
    $this->converte_mes($this->mesSel),
    "<div align=\"right\">".number_format($r['taxa'], 2, ',', '.')."</div>",
    "<div align=\"right\">".number_format($taxa, 2, ',', '.')."</div>",
    "<div align=\"right\">".number_format($dife, 2, ",", ".")."</div>",
    $chk
);
```

Até consegui reordenar o array usando a seguinte função:

```
foreach ($dados as $key => $row) 
{
    $tipo[$key]  = $row[2];
    $val[$key]  = $this->dinheiroInteiro($row[3]);
}

array_multisort($tipo, SORT_ASC, $val, SORT_DESC, $dados);
```

Mas ainda tenho alguns problemas com os valores, e precisaria reiniciar o contador para que ele ficasse começando do *1* após a reordenação do array.

Só para explicar melhor então, após usar o array_multisort, eu reordeno o array pelo tipo de cliente (A, B, C, D)... e que o critério de desempate fosse a 4 coluna (taxa). Só que após a minha reordenção através do multisort o sequencia fica perdido (pois a ordenação inicial dos dados jogados através do while é desfeita), pois a mesma foi feita pelo nome.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: OK, ainda não ficou exatamente claro o que você pretende, porém, pelo menos eu já posso dar um palpite. Você gostaria de renumerar índices do array de volta para o "normal" (0,1,2,3...)? Se for isso, basta passar o array por [array_values()](http://www.php.net/array_values)

Answer (score 2):

Ainda não sei se entendi, mas parece que você quer manter a ordem pelo "nome" como foi gerado no loop while. Se for isso, você poderia incluir mais essa array de referência no array_multisort:

```
foreach ($dados as $key => $row) 
{
    $ref[$key]  = $row[1]; // ou qualquer outro elemento de referência...
    $tipo[$key] = $row[2];
    $val[$key]  = $this->dinheiroInteiro($row[3]);
}

array_multisort($ref, ...SUA_OPÇÃO..., $tipo, SORT_ASC, $val, SORT_DESC, $dados);
```

Assim você teria a array ordenada pelo nome, tendo as segunda e a terceira opções como "desempate".